# Buttons in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

I am new to android and I am trying to learn MVVM. I was wondering do we directly use the setonClick method of a button in main activity or do we have to handle it in the ViewModel.
If we have do it in the ViewModel then how do we do it?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewModel` is preserver for business logic so whatever the logic you want to perform on the button click it shall be defined in the `ViewModel` and in `Activity` you just implement the click listener and call the business logic from that listener.

eg. you want Toast a message on button click so you will declare click listener in the `Activity` like:

```
    button.setOnClicklistener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       view_model.ShowToast();
    })
    
    class YourViewModel extend ViewModel {
    
       public void showToast() {
         // business logic
          Toast.makeText(....);

       }
    }
```

Comment: Displaying a toast from a view model would not be a good idea. You would rather want to use something like SingleLiveEvent in a view model and use that to trigger a toast from your view.

Comment: it's not about displaying the toast, its how we call the business logic in the view model